# Help implementing an op-amp circuit to amplify an AC signal and set its offset above 0

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm currently working on a project for a college class involving sound signal processing (FFT processing using a ESP32).

I am stuck at the implementation of a signal amplifier and offsetting it to prevent negative signals.

The microprocessor of choice was the ESP32, and as far as I found online, the analog input pins have a input range of 0 - 3.3 V. Our input signal can go as high/low as +-120 mV. After a little research I found out that using an op-amp would be a good choice.

I bought a NE5532p and tried using it by following a lot of guides and resources I found online, but none of them worked. I mainly tried to implement both an inverting and non-inverting negative-feedback loop so that I could control the gain, and using a positive DC voltage to offset the signal into a positive value (I think it won't matter much if the lowest value is something like 100 mV above 0 V since once I can read it on the ESP I can manipulate it by code).

So far I have been using mostly circuit simulation software since I only have few days in which I can have access to a osciloscope, and even when it worked on simulations, I couldn't make it work in real life.

I worry there might be something I missed about how op-amps work, or some little detail about them, but it seemed pretty simple once you get a hang of the basics.

If you guys could lend a hand on the subject I would truly appreciate it (it's really frustrating waiting a week to try out the circuit just to see it not working for some unknown reason).

Here´s a sketch I made on TinkerCad mostly to show here, the color code for the wires are given below:
**Pink** is the DC offset voltage into the non-inverting input
**Red** is the DC voltage from the power supply (originally 5 V but transformed into ~3.2 V for the Vcc+)
**Blue** is the  AC signal
**Orange** is the feedback loop/Vout

[image: project made in TinkerCad]

Comment: Btw, I'm aware TinkerCad is not the way to go to simulate the circuit, but I am away from my computer with access to Spice at the moment and I worry a hand-drawn circuit would  be worse

Comment: There's a schematic editor right in the page editor here. I don't know what you're doing with that op-amp model, it doesn't match a single or a dual (what you say you have) in pinout in a way that makes sense to me. If it's supposed to be a single, why would you divide the power supply down? Also the NE5532 is not a single-supply op-amp (dual) - I don't think it's guaranteed to work at all from 5V. It's specified at +/-15V and input range is +/-12V worst case so from 5V you'd have no valid input range.  Notwithstanding the "recommended" minimum of 5V on the datasheet.

Comment: In the "typical" case, both inputs would have to always be between 2V and 3V with a 5V supply for it to work.

Comment: You can't feed your opamp's supply (pin-7) through a voltage divider like that.

Answer (score 6):

In the op-amp's datasheet, you find constraints concerning the acceptable range of input voltages (often called "common mode input voltage range"). Whatever circuit you build must guarantee that the inverting input or non-inverting inputs are *never* presented with a potential that falls outside this range.

For the NE5532, [this datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ne5532-d.pdf) says on page 3 that a typical device will not behave well if either input exceeds +13V, or falls below −13V, with supply potentials of ±15V. In the worst (unlucky) case, this range could be as small as ±12V. We can interpret this to mean that an input potential must always be at least 3V above the op-amp's negative supply potential, and simultaneously never exceed 3V less than positive supply.

As an example, this op-amp is completely unusable for applications with supplies of 0V and +5V, since the input can never drop below (0+3)=+3V or exceed (5-3)=+2V, which is clearly impossible to achieve, or is at best severely restrictive.

Even with a larger single-ended supply of, say, 0V & 15V, the simplest amplifier configuration would fail miserably:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmDZSd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Before you even consider the inverting input, you've already violated the constraints of the op-amp by tying the non-inverting input to 0V. According to the datasheet, if the negative supply to this op-amp is 0V, then it requires (typically) at least +2V at an input.

This is why the datasheet doesn't even talk about using single-ended supplies. Sure, the op-amp can tolerate a potential difference of 30V between its supply pins, so that a single-ended supply of 0V & +30V won't do any damage, but in such cases, the acceptable input potentials will be constrained to between +2V and +28V (or if you are unlucky, +3V to +27V), which isn't very useful. When everything is relative to 0V, it makes much more sense to use a truly negative supply potential, so that the input range includes 0V.

If you wish to use a single-ended supply (in other words the op-amp's negative supply potential is 0V), then you need a device whose input voltage range includes the negative supply, or preferably slightly beyond (below) it.

In addition, you must consider the device's *output* voltage range which *never* includes the supply potentials. Even the best "rail-to-rail" output devices cannot reach closer than ten millivolts or so from the supply potentials.

Consider devices such as the LM358 (LM324) and the TLC2272, which are designed for use with single-ended supplies, and can also work with supplies down to only 3V or so, making them much more useful for anything involving ESP32s, Arduinos or Raspberry Pis and such.

If your source signal potential may be negative, obviously you can't do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxalrR.png)</sup>

It's a classic non-inverting configuration, but the negative supply of 0V constrains the non-inverting input to be always 0V or above (or somewhere in that ballpark, the datasheet will tell you the actual minimum level). Also, the output can't drop below 0V, so all negative inputs will be "clipped".

None of this means you can't use a single-ended supply to process/amplify signals that go negative. There are biasing techniques that can ensure the op-amp inputs remain within acceptable limits, and that centre the output at some point in between the supplies, even if the source signal swings beyond them, but this topic is large and complex.

My understanding of your problem is that you have an input signal that swings between −120mV and +120mV, and that you require an output proportional to the input, which swings between 0V and +3.3V.

To start with, then, this gives you a gain \$A\$ of:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= \frac{3.3 - 0}{0.12 - (-0.12)} \\ \\
&= \frac{3.3}{0.24} \\ \\
&= 13.7 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

When the input is zero, you require an output half-way between 0V and 3.3V, so the offset \$C\$ is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
C &= \frac{3.3 + 0}{2} \\ \\
&= 1.65 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The relationship between \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$  is therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= A\times V_{IN} + C \\ \\
&= 13.7 V_{IN} + 1.65 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

How you implement this depends on what you are actually measuring. If you are trying to measure, for example, the *amplitude* of the source signal, or the source signal is AC and you can tolerate some phase shifting or other frequency dependent behaviour, you may use capacitors to decouple any source DC from the amplifier's own operating point, and set that operating point quite easily:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjMIGs.png)</sup>

This approach requires no negative supply, but suffers from the usual caveats when using capacitive AC coupling. There will always be high-pass filter behaviour, with a cut-off frequency of about 2Hz in this example, and there will be a "settling time" while the capacitors charge to their final average voltages. However, those capacitors keep the op-amp's input potentials always within acceptable bounds. Once settled, the input-output relationship, given a sinusoidal input, will be like this:

[image]

If you require DC coupling (frequency dependency behaviour is undesirable, or the input is very slow moving, or can stay at a constant level for extended periods of time) then capacitors are out of the question, and you'll have to find an alternative solution. It gets complicated if you need gain to be positive, partly because it's really difficult to maintain op-amp input potentials inside the power supply range, when the input goes negative. However, if you are sampling this signal with an ADC then you can perform post-processing in software to compensate for a negative gain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHiEdj.png)</sup>

[image]

This is an inverting, summing amplifier, with gain of −13.7 (for the input signal \$V_{IN}\$), but we offset the output by providing a supplementary negative input potential, with a gain of −1. Obviously, the problem here is the need to derive a negative potential somehow.

One of the reasons that this inverting amplifier approach works, is that op-amp inputs are always zero, or near-zero, due to the "[virtual earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground)" principle employed here. As long as the op-amp you use is comfortable with inputs *slightly* below the negative supply rail, it will work just fine.

The moral of the story might be that concerning op-amps, everything is complicated by the use of single-ended supplies. Since this is a college project, I imagine it will be easy for you to obtain a negative supply and just avoid this hurdle altogether. A word of warning, though: if you power your op-amp from dual supplies, then it can output negative potentials, and that can kill your ADC. Take care.

Since you already have an NE5532, and if I assume you can source a negative supply from somewhere, maybe your best bet is an adaptation of the above circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjCDgO.png)</sup>

[image]

You must use at least ±6V as supplies to the op-amp, and I've adjusted R3 to keep the output offset the same, given the increased negative potential.

The two diodes D1 and D2 clamp the output close to 0V and 3.3V in the case where the op-amp produces something outside that range, just to protect whatever comes next. Perhaps your ADC already has input protection diodes, in which case you may omit D1 and D2. R4 is there to limit current that flows when clamping occurs, to protect the op-amp and ADC.

Hope all this gives you some sense of direction.